# Access VIM session started by another process - Script/SU/Programme

Tags: linux, session, vim

I have a challenge and was wondering how to complete it.

A  process in the background would start VIM using "su - user1 -c vim file.txt" whilst logged into root. I from the user1 need to access that VIM session. I can't read the file.txt directly but the contents I need is in the VIM session.

Is there anyway to switch to a VIM process that is already running? I have tried killing the process to force it to dump to a swap file but that's not working well.

Answer (score 2):

If your vim is compiled with the `+clientserver` option (check by calling `:version` from within vim) then you can open vim with a server instance using `vim --servername FOO` and then connect to that server in a separate terminal using `vim --servername FOO --remote file.txt`. You can even send a valid Ex command to the server using `vim --servername FOO--remote-send ':g/Foo/d'`

For your use case I imagine you'd want to send a command like `:w !anyTerminalCommand > anotherFile.txt`

For more information, checkout `:h clientserver`